# Convert a Map of Tuple into a Map of Sets

Tags: scala, group-by, tuples

In my dao I receive a tuple[String,String] of which _1 is non-unique and _2 is unique. I groupBy based on _1 to get this -

```
val someCache : Map[String, List[(String, String)]]
```

This is obviously wasteful since _1 is being repeated for all values of the Map. Since _2 is unique, what I want is something like -

```
val someCache : Map[String, Set[String]]
```

i.e. group by _1 and use as key and use the paired _2s as value of type Set[String]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo(ts: Seq[(String, String)]): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
  ts.foldLeft(Map[String, Set[String]]()) { (agg, t) =>
    agg + (t._1 -> (agg.getOrElse(t._1, Set()) + t._2))
  }
}


scala> foo(List(("1","2"),("1","3"),("2","3")))
res4: Map[String,Set[String]] = Map(1 -> Set(2, 3), 2 -> Set(3))
```

Comment: `case (agg, (k, v)) =>` would have probably been better

Comment: could you elaborate a little on this :
    
    (agg.getOrElse(t._1, Set()) + t._2)

specifically, why Set() as getOrElse second argument ?

Comment: @Vaibhav if there is no value yet assigned to that key (`t._1`), then `getOrElse` returns a new empty set (`Set()`). if there is already a value assigned to that key, then `getOrElse` returns the value in the map. In either case, you next at `t._2` to the set.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution is to map over all elements and convert each list to set:

```
someCache.map{ case (a, l) => a -> l.map{ _._2 }.toSet }
```

You could also use `mapValues` but you should note that it creates a lazy collection and performs transformation on every access to value.